# Writing in the first column first when using multicol package

Tags: multicol

I'm using the multicol package to enable writing with 3 columns or more, however I realise that the default behaviour is to balance out the content of the page with the columns.

But this is not what I want, since what I want is to fill out the first column first, then the second, and so on.

Does anyone know how to enable this in multicol package? Or does anyone know any other packages that can enable this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem, just use the `multicols*` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. I didn't need the lipsum though. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @the_great_monkey: `lipsum`'s just a nice little package for generating "filler" text. You'll see it used in many answers on tex.stackexchange. Makes for short examples, that's all.