# LaTeX version warning for multicol package

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, multicol

## Background

While implementing [Frank Mittelbach's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122474/2148), the `pdflatex` command returned the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 13, version
               `2011/12/20' of package multicol,
               but only version
               `2011/06/27 v1.7a multicolumn formatting (FMi)'
               is available.
```

Accompanied shortly thereafter by the following error:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 199--199
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 dic-tum gravida mau-
```

## Code

The code is straightforward:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mccolaction}

\newif\ifinlast
\def\columnbreakunlesslast{%
    \docolaction{\typeout{in first column}\inlastfalse}%
                           {\typeout{in middle column}\inlastfalse}%
                           {\typeout{in last  column}\inlasttrue}%
    \unless \ifinlast \columnbreak \fi
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
\section{First}
\lipsum[1-2]

\columnbreakunlesslast

\section{Second}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

## Problem

I tried the [following](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution) commands:

```
tlmgr update --self
tlmgr update --list
tlmgr update --all
```

Each returned with "*no updates available*".

## Question

How do I upgrade the multicols package using TeX Live 2013 on Linux?

Comment: The newest version of multicol at CTAN and so in TeX Live is `2011/06/27`. Maybe Frank has a newer version on his machine ;-)

Comment: http://latex-project.org/svnroot/latex2e-public/required/tools/

Comment: The problem seems to have been resolved by a new CTAN upload. As such, it may be of limited use to future visitors who have an updated distribution.

Comment: I think that Frank's answer for updating the distribution manually might be useful for anyone who receives a similar LaTeX warning.

Comment: @Werner given that the core LaTeX is only updated ver seldom that is only partially true.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: We already have [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) and [Where do I place my own `.sty` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://goo.gl/ByVnz), the latter of which is similar in nature to what FMi suggests (in my opinion). Closing is not bad...

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Wouldn't an upload to CTAN automatically form part of an update, regardless of whether it's part of the "core LaTeX" tools?

Comment: @Werner: Running `latex tools.ins` as Frank suggests is not an answer in either of those questions, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, didn't realize that the SVN version never made it to CTAN. So the correct code for `mccolaction.sty` that should work for both versions of `multicol` looks like this:

```
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ProvidesPackage{mccolaction}
          [2013/07/07 v0.9c  column actions for multicolumn formatting (FMi)]
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{multicol}[2011/06/27]
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%   Determining the current column in multicols is difficult because
%   (in contrast to the twocolumn mode of standard LaTeX) the
%   multicols columns are determined very late in the game and due to
%   the balancing routine it is not known where a piece of text is
%   going to end up at the time the text is typeset. Only afterwards,
%   when everything has be typeset into a single long galley, that
%   galley is split into individual columns (at the very end in a
%   possibly huge set of trials to balance the column material.
%
%   Therefore the approach taken here is to write out a single line
%   into the .aux file whenever a column is finally typeset:
%\begin{verbatim}
% \mc@col@status{<number>}
%\end{verbatim}
%   The number in the argument denotes the different kind of column: 1
%   for left column 2 for any middle column and 3 for the final column.
%
%   We only set this up for the LR typesetting case here, something
%   similar could be done for the RL version:
%    \begin{macrocode}
%
% there has been a code change after 2011/06 that never made it to CTAN
% but only into the SVN repository
% so we need to provide two different versions:
\@ifpackagelater{multicol}{2011/06/28}
{%
\patchcmd{\LR@column@boxes}{\box\count@}%
         {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\mc@col@status
              {\ifmc@firstcol 1\else 2\fi}}%
          \mc@firstcolfalse
          \box\count@}%
         {\typeout{juhu!}}{\typeout{oje!}}%
\patchcmd{\LR@column@boxes}{\box\mult@rightbox}%
         {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\mc@col@status{3}}%
          \box\mult@rightbox}%
         {\typeout{juhu!}}{\typeout{oje!}}%
}
{%
\patchcmd{\page@sofar}{\box\count@}%
         {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\mc@col@status
              {\ifmc@firstcol 1\else 2\fi}}%
          \mc@firstcolfalse
          \box\count@}%
         {\typeout{juhu!}}{\typeout{oje!}}%
\patchcmd{\page@sofar}{\box\mult@rightbox}%
         {\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\mc@col@status{3}}%
          \box\mult@rightbox}%
         {\typeout{juhu!}}{\typeout{oje!}}%
}
\newif\ifmc@firstcol
\mc@firstcoltrue
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%   Need to reinitiate \verb=\mc@align@columns= as this was let to
%   the old definition of \verb=\LR@column@boxes=.
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\LRmulticolcolumns

%   Whenever we want to do something that depends on the current
%   column we execute \verb=\docolaction=. This command takes one
%   optional and three mandatory arguments. The mandatory ones denote
%   what to do if this is a ``left'', ``middle'', or ``right'' column
%   and the optional one is simply there to say what to do if we don't
%   know (default is to use the ``left'' column action in that case).
%
%   We use one counter \verb=\mc@col@check@num= to generate us unique
%   label names. Each time we execute \verb=\docolaction= we increment
%   this counter to get a new name.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcount\mc@col@check@num
%    \end{macrocode}

%   The generated ``labels'' are named
%   \verb=\mc@col-\the\mc@col@check@num= and they hold as values the
%   numbers 1, 2, or 3 denoting the current column type.

%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand\docolaction[4][1]{%
 \global\advance\mc@col@check@num\@ne
 \edef\mc@col@type{\expandafter\ifx
               \csname mc@col-\the\mc@col@check@num\endcsname\relax
                  0\else
                  \csname mc@col-\the\mc@col@check@num\endcsname
               \fi}%
%    \end{macrocode}
%    We prefix with 0 so that an unknown label (that returns
%   \verb=\relax=) will result in case 0
%    \begin{macrocode}
 \ifcase \mc@col@type\relax
%    \end{macrocode}
%    If column is unknown we use the default action or the action
%   denoted by the optional argument (so that arg can take the value
%   1, 2, 3)
%    \begin{macrocode}
     \ifcase #1\or #2\or#3\or#4\fi   % 0 not known use first col as default
  \or
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Otherwise we know (or think we know) that this is a first, middle,
%   or last column:
%    \begin{macrocode}
     #2%  % 1 First col
  \or
     #3%  % 2 any middle col
  \or
     #4%  % 3 last col
  \else
    \ERROR
  \fi
%    \end{macrocode}
%    But how does the column number get associated with our label? We
%   do do this by writing another line into the aux file at this point:
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \edef\next{\write\@auxout
     {\string\mc@set@col@status{mc@col-\the\mc@col@check@num}%
                               {\mc@col@type}}}%
  \next
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%   Because of extra data writing to the aux file the aux file will
%   now contain something like the following after the document is
%   processed the first time:
%\begin{verbatim}
%\relax
%\mc@col@status{1}
%\mc@set@col@status{lcol-1}{0}
%\mc@col@status{2}
%\mc@set@col@status{lcol-2}{0}
%\mc@col@status{3}
%\mc@set@col@status{lcol-3}{0}
%\mc@col@status{1}
%\mc@col@status{2}
%\mc@col@status{3}
%\mc@set@col@status{lcol-4}{0}
%\end{verbatim}
%   The \verb=\mc@col@status= line denotes the column type and has been
%   writting out just before corresponding the column box was placed
%   onto the page.
%   The\verb=\mc@set@col@status= lines have been written out as part
%   of shipping the column boxes out, e.g.,
%   \verb=\mc@set@col@status{lcol-1}{0}= was therefore somewhere within
%   the first column as it appears between \verb=\mc@col@status{1}=
%   and  \verb=\mc@col@status{2}=
%   The second argument in that line is the value used in the previous
%   run (or zero if there was no previous run. We can use this to
%   determine if a rerun is necessary.
%
%   Thus with this knowledge we can set things up to get the labels
%   working.
%
%   When the aux file is read in \verb=\mc@col@status= is used to set
%   \verb=\mc@curr@col@status=:
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\mc@col@status#1{\gdef\mc@curr@col@status{#1}}
%    \end{macrocode}

%   And when \verb=\mc@set@col@status= is executed we can simply set
%   up the label by associating it with the \verb=\mc@curr@col@status=
%   and ignore the second argument:
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\mc@set@col@status#1#2{%
   \global\expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\mc@curr@col@status}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%   The above definition is being used when the \texttt{.aux} file is
%   read in at the beginning. At the end we need a different
%   definition to test if another typesetting run is needed. There we
%   compare the value used in the current run (stored in the second
%   argument) with the value used on the next run. If those two values
%   differ we set \verb=@tempswa= to false which will trigger the
%   ``Label(s) may have changed'' warning.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\AtEndDocument{\def\mc@set@col@status#1#2{%
     \ifnum #2=\mc@curr@col@status\else
       \@tempswatrue
     \fi}%
}
%    \end{macrocode}
```

Due to the check the code above with work with both the version on CTAN dated 2011/06/27 and the one in the SVN.

To answer you question on updating your distribution: it is unfortunately a little manual: pick up the `multicol.dtx` and `tools.ins` from the SVN at http://latex-project.org/svnroot/latex2e-public/required/tools .

Place them into an empty directory and run `latex tools.ins`. Ignore the errors about missing files (or  alternatively pick up all files in that directory from SVN). That should then generate the `multicol.sty` file for you that you can place into your local `texmf` tree or replace the copy in your main tree or for testing simply use it in the same directory as your `.tex` file.