# ConTeXt: Conditional column break

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, context, two-column

## Background

Trying to determine whether a column break must be inserted on a two-column page. There are multiple sections on the page. Before the last section on the page, I want to insert a column break, but only if within the first column and only if there is sufficient space in the second column (i.e., without forcing a page break).

## Problem

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
\starttext
    \startcolumns[n=2, balance=no]
    \startsection[title=Section1]
    \input knuth
    \stopsection
    \startsection[title=Section2]
    \input zapf
    \stopsection
    \column
    \startsection[title=Section3]
    \input knuth
    \stopsection

    \stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

The `\column` break should not be applied because section 3 is in the second column, which causes an undesired page break. To clarify, the condition to determine whether or not to break the column should be independent of the text itself. For example, something like:

```
\setuphead[chapter][
  before={\startcolumns[n=2, balance=no,]},
  after={\stopcolumns},
]

% If the section is the last section in the chapter
% *and* the section is not in the last column *and*
% inserting a column break does not cause pagination...
\setuphead[section][
  before={%
    \if_last_section{%
      \if_not_last_column{%
        \if_fits_in_last_column_without_pagination{\columnbreak}
      }
    }
  },
]

\starttext
  \startchapter
    \startsection[title=Section1]
    \input knuth
    \stopsection
    \startsection[title=Section2]
    \input zapf
    \stopsection
    \startsection[title=Section3]
    \input knuth
    \stopsection
  \stopchapter
\stoptext
```

## Question

How do you force ConTeXt to insert a column break if a section is in the first column, but not if the section is in the second column?

## Related

Very similar question for LaTeX:

- [Column break only if within first column of multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122360/column-break-only-if-within-first-column-of-multicol)

Using LaTeX, the following code -- part of the document class -- helped dynamically determine whether or not a column break should be present:

```
\def\columnbreakunlesslast{%
  \docolaction{\typeout{in first column}\inlastfalse}%
              {\typeout{in middle column}\inlasttrue}%
              {\typeout{in last column}\inlasttrue}%
  \unless \ifinlast \columnbreak \fi
}
```

This allowed documents to be written such that manually inserting column breaks was not necessary.

Comment: `\page` and `\page[disable]` will accomplish it (of course, wherever you wish to force the page break). Either way, irrespective whether `\column` is applied.

Comment: @doed: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122474/2148 -- it uses `\docolaction{\typeout{in first column}` to determine whether the text is still in the first column. I'm looking for something like that.

Comment: The content is user-generated. I don't necessarily know where the "last section" will be within the document.

Comment: Yes Dave. I realized that. great question though.

Comment: I'm wondering not only if that answer it's useful enough to deserve a vote. I can care less about the bounty points. Since the question expired for one, and secondly because I'd just like to know what would someone who is actively involved with ConTeXt would do. It would be good to find out what Hagen himself would do in this case.

Comment: @doed: My software generates books automatically using user-generated content (as per the related question); a manual solution will not work.

Comment: At no point `mccolaction` may be deployed with user-generated content. Leave out that `\columnbreakunlesslast` in LaTeX and see what happens. For that matter Here is with `\columnbreak` instead, which accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Even with the `mccolaction` dated 7/7/2013, the `\columnbreakunlesslast` must be tweaked manually, or else it won't work.

Comment: @doed: The `columnbreakunlesslast` was tweaked (as shown in the question), but it was tweaked in the document class file, not within any document.

Comment: How is it that the code of `mccolaction` allowed documents not to have a `\columnbreakunlesslast`? For the sake of clarity, unless you include `\columnbreakunlesslast` in the document, whether 'user-generated' or not, it won't break the columns as originally intended.

Comment: I find it distastefully fallacious to prove a point at the expense or the lack thereof, of a feature (more and more code) of an unrelated system, in this case LaTeX, for this question for one, was geared toward ConTeXt, but you seemed more biased of Mittlebach's answer, since you accepted it as absolute and final, even though, in this respect, you could probably go farther with ConTeXt. Did you know that ConTeXt stretches and shrinks more than LaTeX? No pun intended.

Comment: When you posted the question, I was unsure what you wanted to accomplish, and to make matters worse, I hadn't even paid attention to the package `mccolaction`, until after you linked the similarly related LaTeX question. But upon closer look , you can try this out in ConTeXt. For example,  `\vfil\unpenalty\vbox \input bla bla bla`, with the addition of say, `\columnbreak` or a `\vfilll`, and see how it becomes easily stretchable and shrinkable.  In LaTeX for example,  let `\lipsum` substitute `\input`. And as you can see, as of this writing, this is unlikely attainable in LaTeX.

Comment: @doed: I am looking for a solution (in ConTeXt) that does not intermingle presentation with content. This means that the `\columbreak` must be conditionally applied outside of `\starttext`. I have clarified the intent with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will try to keep it simple. You have two options, the first one:

```
\columnbreak
```

The second option is to apply some glue with `\vfil`, it all depends the amount of stretchability or shrinkability, for more glue apply `\vfill` or `\vfilll` to the box.
 Make a vertical box with either `\vtop` or `\vbox`. The latter is recommended, for the simple fact that it could be stretched and shrink and stretched and shrink some more  with `\columnbreak` or `\vfill`. Did I say that ConTeXt can expand more than LaTeX?

So in ConTeXt the code would look as follows:

```
\vfil
\vbox{%
\input tufte
}
```

```
\vfil
\vbox{%
\input knuth\columnbreak % or \vfill
}
```

Consider this for example.

```
\starttext

\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
    \startcolumns[n=3, balance=no]

    \section[1]

\input knuth

\section[2]

    \input zapf

    \section[3]

\vfil
\vbox{%
\input knuth 

}

\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

[image]

Or better yet, this one.

```
\def\doed\par{%
\vfil
\vbox{%
\input tufte
}}

\starttext

\hyphenation{wh-e-at}
\hyphenation{me-r-ge}
\hyphenation{st-r-ong-ly}
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
    \startcolumns[n=3, balance=no]

\section[1]

\input knuth

\section[2]

\input zapf

\section[3]

\doed  %The first break is applied. 

\input zapf

\section[4]

\doed %The second one follows. 

\input zapf
\input knuth
    \stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

[image]
[image]

Or column break after first column

```
\def\doed\par{%
\vfil
\vbox{%
\input tufte
}}


\starttext

\hyphenation{wh-e-at}
\hyphenation{me-r-ge}
\hyphenation{st-r-ong-ly}
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
    \startcolumns[n=3, balance=no]

\section[1]

\input knuth

\section[2]

\doed 

\dorecurse{3}{\input zapf}

\section[3]

\doed

\input zapf

\input zapf

\section[4]

\doed

\input zapf

\input zapf

\section[5]

\doed

\input knuth

    \stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

[image]

[image]

And here is with `\columnbreak` which accomplishes the same thing than `\columnbreakunlesslast` from LaTeX

```
\starttext

\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
    \startcolumns[n=3, balance=no]

\section[1]

\input knuth

\columnbreak

\section[2]

\dorecurse{2}{\input zapf}

    \section[3]

\input tufte

\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Does ConTeXt change the meaning of `\vfill` and `\unpenalty`? If it doesn't, `\vfill\unpenalty` is completely equivalent to `\vfill`, as there is no penalty `\unpenalty` can act on.

Comment: Indeed! Although equivalent is not doing a thing. It's the same as adding a `\unskip` when no `\medskip` is present. I'll edit it.